# Increase decimal column scale without affecting data

Tags: sql-server

I have to increase scale of a decimal column of a table having records in billions in sql server 2008 database.

Actual:   `Column decimal(15, 2) NULL`

Required: `Column decimal(15, 4) NULL`

I tried `ALTER TABLE` with `ALTER COLUMN` but the statement taking too long to be completed because of data.

Is there any way to increase scale without affecting data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ...` is the **only way** to achieve this....

Comment: @marc_s: What about recreating the table and then delete the old table? Could that be faster?

Comment: @wewesthemenace: if the table really has **billions** of rows as the OP claims - probably not....

Comment: @marc_s: ahh. Thanks. Even if the insert would be in batch?

Comment: Also: be careful - with `Decimal(15,2)`, you have **13 digits** before the decimal point - with `decimal(15,4)`, you're down to only 11 digits..... if you have really large numbers, you might loose data.

Comment: Thanks @marc_s i really neglected that i have to change that to `decimal(17, 4)`

Comment: +1 to @marc_s, I had a failing schema compare/update and was afraid I would have to do a manual alter statement on local->qa->prod, this was a big help.